# check data is in array flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i create database to store 'post like' and want to check the 'user_id_liked' has like the post or not.
[this is the array model from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKD6q.png). i decided to select all items from database and store it to that array. for example i want to check if "id-2" is in that array or not. how can i do that programatically on flutter? i try like this before but it seems that i cant get result that i want.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List TotalLike = [];
  Future getLike() async {
    var response = await http
        .post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "id_post": "post-9d18d0a280",
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        try {
          TotalLike = json.decode(response.body);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        TotalLike;
        print(TotalLike);
      });
      return TotalLike;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getLike();
    super.initState();
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            color: TotalLike.contains("id-2") ? Colors.amber : Colors.pink,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? The code look fine. Maybe you colud try to use `any` like so `TotalLike.any(x => x == "id-2")`

Comment: id-2 from array didn't detected but in the array its available. also its already solved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var contain = someDataModel.comments.where((element) => element['Id'] == 'id-2');
      if (contain.isEmpty){
        _isILike = false;
      } else {
        _isILike = true;
      }
```

Comment: i already tried that code before but i'm a bit confuse with 'someDataModel' because that variable detected as an error. i have change the 'comments'  into the list name but it seems didn't work as well.

Comment: @MengQing if your comments is list then is should work. do one thing write simple Code create list and find in it.